# $q$ is prime and $k=2,3,4,\dots$ . Show that if $x\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x^2\equiv x\pmod {q^k}$ then $x\equiv 0\pmod {q^k}$ or $x\equiv 1\pmod {q^k}$

Tags: prime-numbers

Considering the *or* condition in this statement, would I be proving both could be true or two separate cases? Also, is there some sort of reduction required?
I know there exists a formula for $x^2\equiv x\pmod {q^k}$ but something about the exponent is throwing me off, please help!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  We have
$$\eqalign{x^2\equiv x\pmod{q^k}\quad
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad x^2-x\equiv0\pmod{q^k}\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad x(x-1)\equiv0\pmod{q^k}\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad q^k\mid x(x-1)\ .\cr}$$
Now can you explain why one of the statements $q^k\mid x$ and $q^k\mid x-1$ must be true?